# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, select, where-clause

Could someone please help me with the Oracle query to search text appended with any non-alphabet character Or Space
Eg:-
INDIA- 
INDIA,
INDIA 
-INDIA
,INDIA
 INDIA

The query which I wrote to search INDIA retrieved rows with "INDIAA" as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE (REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME,'INDIA[,_)("-]') 
     OR REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME,'[,_)("-]INDIA')
     OR REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME,'[,_)("-]INDIA[,_)("-]')
     OR  REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME,'\sINDIA\s')
     OR  REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME,'\sINDIA') 
     OR REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME, 'INDIA\s') -- this line is causing problem
     OR REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME, '^INDIA$'))
```

Thank You!

Comment: Examples of valid matches and non-matches would help.

Comment: yeah... I'm missing the point here. Are we looking for all values that contains "INDIA" and some non-alphanumeric character?

Comment: As others have suggested, could you please add more examples of valid and invalid matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
regexp_like(column_name, '(^|\W)INDIA(\W|$)')
```

This searches for `'INDIA'`, surrounded by non-word characters (`\W`), or at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: wise regex. I was thinking of a similar thing